# Can you specify a job from Scheduler in Azure to never have an 'Ending On'?

Tags: azure, scheduler

I have a job being created through Azure's Scheduler that I never want to end (i.e. I want to run daily forever). When creating a job it has an 'ending on' calendar type field. Is there any way to specify, no, I want this to 'go on and on my friend'?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can. After creating the job, edit it and there will be a 'NO END DATE' radio button option. It's weird that you can't specify that when creating the job though.